# How can I read id from jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 var $div = $('<div/>', {
         css: css,
         id: "testId" + product.id
 });
```

How can I access this `id` from this `$div`..

For now I hardcoded it when fetching from html, like this:

```
$('#testId_a2732d9e-db81-4c2f-85aa-563856e53ff4').css('background', '');
```

But I would like to access it directly in my javascript file from this `$div`

Thanks

Comment: `$div.prop('id')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for help mate, looks like it's fetching id, but now it says $div.prop(...).css is not a function, what that might be

Comment: That's because `prop()` returns a string. You can't call `css()` on a string, you need a jQuery object, which is in the `$div` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get any attribute value.

```js
$div.attr('id')
```

Comment: Use `prop()` when dealing with properties of the Element object.

Comment: Yes, but `id` HTML attribute has 1:1 mapping to property. So, in this case we would be getting the same result. Right?

Comment: @KumarSwapnil Probably, but when you want an element's property, it's better to use `.prop()` than to use `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have access to this variable, then

```
$div.attr('id')
```

Comment: Use `prop()` when dealing with properties of the Element object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop()`:

```js
var product = { id: "abcd" };

var $div = $('<div/>', {
   id: "testId" + product.id
 });
 
 console.log($div.prop('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but now with this modifications I got this error ` $div.prop(...).css`  is not a function

Comment: @Roxy'Pro You said you wanted to get the ID. The ID is a string, so it doesn't have a `.css()` method. What are you trying to do?